# Get all the elements of a type Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have declared a type of objects as follows:

```
type([coffee, tea, lemonade, water, coke, beer]: drink).
```

How can I get a list of all the objects of type `drink`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use unification, like:

```
type(L : drink).
```

This will unify `L` with that list, like:

```
?- type(L: drink).
L = [coffee, tea, lemonade, water, coke, beer].
```

That being said, it is not very common to use a colon (`:`) here, usually one uses different parameters. Furthermore lists are not very common in facts either, since you hereby lose the ability to easily check what the type of `tea` is for example.

It is more idiomatic to write:

```
type(coffee, drink).
type(tea, drink).
type(lemonade, drink).
type(water, drink).
type(coke, drink).
type(beer, drink).
```

We can for example query for elements of the type `drink`:

```
?- type(D, drink).
D = coffee ;
D = tea ;
D = lemonade ;
D = water ;
D = coke ;
D = beer.
```

Or to query what the type of `water` is:

```
?- type(water, T).
T = drink.
```

Check if a `newspaper` or `coke` are `drink`s:

```
?- type(newspaper, drink).
false.

?- type(coke, drink).
true.
```

and enumerate over all items with their type:

```
?- type(X, T).
X = coffee,
T = drink ;
X = tea,
T = drink ;
X = lemonade,
T = drink ;
X = water,
T = drink ;
X = coke,
T = drink ;
X = beer,
T = drink.
```

You can then create a list with the [**`findall/3`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3) predicate:

```
?- findall(D, type(D, drink), Ds).
Ds = [coffee, tea, lemonade, water, coke, beer].
```

Answer (score 1):

If you insisted on the representation, you could use `memberchk/2` to define an object-type relation like this:

```
object_type(O, T) :-
    type(Os:T),
    memberchk(O, Os).
```